# Did I Write this Statement Form in Polish Notation Correctly?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, notation, propositional-calculus, polish-notation

My goal is the write the statement form in the first line in Polish notation. The last line is my solution. The intermediate steps show my work.

\begin{aligned}
     &((((A\Rightarrow B)\Rightarrow(C\Rightarrow D))\land(\lnot A))\lor C)\\      &\lor(((A\Rightarrow B)\Rightarrow(C\Rightarrow D))\land(\lnot A))C\\
     &\lor(((A\Rightarrow B)\Rightarrow(C\Rightarrow D))\land\lnot A)C\\
     &\lor(((\Rightarrow AB)\Rightarrow(\Rightarrow CD))\land\lnot A)C\\
     &\lor((\Rightarrow(\Rightarrow AB)(\Rightarrow CD))\land\lnot A)C\\
     &\lor((\Rightarrow\Rightarrow AB\Rightarrow CD)\land\lnot A)C\\
     &\lor(\land\Rightarrow\Rightarrow AB\Rightarrow CD\lnot A)C\\
     &\lor\land\Rightarrow\Rightarrow AB\Rightarrow CD\lnot AC\\
     \end{aligned}

(This is part of exercise 1.18(c) in Elliott Mendelson's *Introduction to Mathematical Logic*, Sixth Edition. I am self-studying that book.)

Comment: The solution appears correct to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion into Polish notation is correct.

Let us record the conventional letters of Polish notation for reference:

\begin{alignat*}{3}
&Negation  &\qquad  \neg\varphi &\qquad  \mathrm{N}\varphi\psi\\
&Conjunction  &\qquad \varphi\wedge\psi &\qquad \mathrm{K}\varphi\psi\\
&Inclusive(weak)\, disjunction  &\qquad \varphi\vee\psi &\qquad \mathrm{A}\varphi\psi\\
&Exclusive(strong)\, disjunction   &\qquad \varphi\not\equiv\psi &\qquad \mathrm{J}\varphi\psi\\
&Material\,implication  &\qquad \varphi\rightarrow\psi &\qquad \mathrm{C}\varphi\psi\\
&Material\,equivalence  &\qquad \varphi\leftrightarrow\psi &\qquad \mathrm{E}\varphi\psi\\
&Sheffer\,stroke(non\!-\!conjunction) &\qquad \varphi\mid\psi &\qquad \mathrm{D}\varphi\psi\\
&Peirce's\,arrow(non\!-\!disjunction) &\qquad \varphi\downarrow\psi &\qquad \mathrm{X}\varphi\psi\\
&Possibility  &\qquad \Diamond\varphi &\qquad \mathrm{M}\varphi\\
&Necessity  &\qquad \Box\varphi &\qquad \mathrm{L}\varphi\\
&Universal\,quantifier  &\qquad \forall x\varphi &\qquad \mathrm{\Pi}x\varphi\\
&Existential\,quantifier &\qquad \exists x\varphi &\qquad \mathrm{\Sigma}x\varphi\\
\end{alignat*}

So, we can rewrite the formula in question as

$$\mathrm{AKCC}ab\mathrm{C}cd\mathrm{N}ac$$

In case that the purpose is merely a notational conversion, it might be more practical to begin from the innermost parentheses: $((((\mathrm{C}ab)\Rightarrow(C\Rightarrow D))\land(\lnot A))\lor C)$ and so on.

(There may be variations in symbols; some may prefer $\not\leftrightarrow$ instead of $\not\equiv$, etc.).